# Does Jennifer Granholm's 'Perfect Game' proclamation carry any actual weight?

Tags: united-states, michigan

On June 3, 2010, in response to [The Almost Perfect Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armando_Galarraga's_near-perfect_game), then-governor Granholm [issued a proclamation](https://www.michigan.gov/formergovernors/0,4584,7-212-57648_21974-237961--,00.html), that reads, in part:

> **Now, Therefore, be it Resolved** that I, Jennifer M. Granholm, governor of the state of Michigan, do hearby declare Armando Galarraga to have pitched a perfect game...

Could someone later use this proclamation to legal effect? For example, could a person who had placed a bet on a perfect game occurring that day collect?  Or is it simply a way to indicate support for the home team without any legal weight?

Answer (score 1):

The rules of professional baseball are set by the MLB so you would have to go with that for anything official unless the parties agreed to use the proclamation.

The proclamation references the error of the umpire. Therefore, it is admitting that it was not declared a perfect game, so if you did use it you would be admitting that too.

> "Whereas, an umpire's missed call resulted in Armando Galarraga being charged a hit that clearly should have been an out; and,https://www.michigan.gov/formergovernors/0,4584,7-212-57648_21974-237961--,00.html

Yes it is supposed to be support.

Answer (score 0):

Proclamations such as these are purely ceremonial and carry no legal weight, except to the extent they include directives to the governor's employees, who would generally be required to implement those instructions.

No one would be able use the proclamation to prove much of anything beyond the fact that the governor issued it.